# DOM Manipulation triggered by CSS Media Queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using CSS media queries to deliver different views of my website. Basically just depending on the width i show/hide certain elements.

Now I also need to move stuff around depending on this width. That means a DOM element must move to a different place in the DOM tree.

Since it contains forms and other unique stuff, I can not just have it in the DOM tree twice and toggle visibility. I really need to move it around, preferably with jQuery.

I have already found this:
http://css-tricks.com/media-query-change-detection-in-javascript-through-css-animations/
But is it really the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It isn't the only way :)

[enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) - A lightweight, pure JavaScript library for responding to CSS media queries.

[intention.js](http://intentionjs.com/) - Offers a light-weight and clear way to dynamically restructure HTML in a responsive manner

Comment: @clamp That's up to you and depends your project specific needs.

Answer (score 3):

No, not the only way.

You can always use js to make the page responsive.

Another good js plugin is [response.js](http://responsejs.com/)

But the most important thing is the concept of how to make effective media queries.

Now the good tendency is making media query based on your page content rather than some fixed width break points.

Here is some interesting articles on this.

1. [7 Habits of Highly Effective Media Queries](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/?utm_source=CSS-Weekly&utm_campaign=Issue-78&utm_medium=email)
2. [Determining breakpoints for a responsive design](http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/determining-breakpoints-responsive-design-8122871)

Comment: `Now the good tendency is making media query based on your page content rather than some fixed width break points` This is an excellent point! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.onResize` event to detect a change in width and work accordingly with that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to move the element to a different place in the DOM tree - you need to move it to a different location on the screen. Proper web development has separation of content and presentation - the location of information in the HTML document can have little to do with where it is found on screen. This is not much space to talk about CSS positioning, but I would check out position: absolute, position: fixed and float.

Comment: yeah i know, but that is not possible in my specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use use vanilla js

```js
if (window.innerWidth < 768) 
{
    
//do something here 
   
 }
```