# Reorganize DIV's under specific resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 DIV's:

```
<div class="a">Lorem 1</a>
<div class="b">Lorem 2</a>
```

What is the easiest way to change their order on resolutions smaller than 480px (mobile)?

I tried playing with appendTo and prependTo but no luck.
The main issue is that this only needs to happen on resolutions under 480px...

Any advice?

Comment: Maybe this post helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030003/dom-manipulation-triggered-by-css-media-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript :

**html**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="a">Lorem 1</a>
    <div class="b">Lorem 2</a>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        if( $(window).width() < 480 ) {
            $('.b').insertBefore($('.a'));
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/veny2zua/1/

basically it's very simple. You just listen to the `resize()` event and everytime you check the `window's width()`, if it's under 480px, you just inverse the two.

***edit :***

in case you need the div with class "a" to come back first when the width goes over 480px, I wrote you the script to make it work :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var $a = $('.a');
    var $b = $('.b');

    $( window ).resize(function() {
        if( $(window).width() < 480 ) {
            $b.insertBefore($a);
        } else {
            if( $a.prev().is("div.b") ) {
                $a.insertBefore($b);  
            }
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/veny2zua/2/
I tested fast, seems like it's working, but care of the possible bugs ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browsers you need to support, you could use a combination of flexbox and media queries.

Given this markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a">Lorem 1</div>
    <div class="b">Lorem 2</div>
</div>
```

You can reverse the two below your breakpoint using this CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
   .container{
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row-reverse;
   }
}
```

That will effectively flip the two. However, [browser support varies and you will need to use the appropriate vendor prefixes.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with [**`Flexbox`**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You do not require Javascript or jQuery. However the browser support is [**`>=IE10`**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) { /* Change it to 480px, 768px for demo purpose */
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* Vertical stacking */
  }
  .a {
    order: 2; /* Default is 1, thus 2 will be higher than .b's order 1. */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">Lorem 1</div>
  <div class="b">Lorem 2</div>
</div>
```